# Loading a csv with Python: "ValueError: could not convert string 'ï»¿6799.2' to float64 at row 0, column 1"

Tags: python, csv

I've been trying to load a small .csv file into python to use a particular package (CADET). The package loads the file using the following:

```
data = numpy.loadtxt(experiment["csv"], delimiter=",")
```

My CSV looks like this in Excel:
[CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IA6ol.png)

And it looks fine opening it in notepad, here it is again:

```
6799.2,1.04E-07
7111.8,1.38E-07
7417.2,1.02E-07
7726.8,2.45E-08
8036.4,5.33E-09
8346,2.20E-09
8655.6,1.05E-09
8965.2,5.68E-10
```

Running the code results in the error

```
ValueError: could not convert string 'ï»¿6799.2' to float64 at row 0, column 1.
```

I feel like maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I've been trying everything to get around this. Things I've tried:

- Changing the values in the CSV to other arbitrary numbers
- Changing CSV formatting to move things around etc.
- Using different CSV files

In all cases it gives "ï»¿" then the first value, but I have no idea where that's coming from. I've used this package in the past with other data files without any issues, but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong now. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips for future questions. One thing is to start with your own research; I found that question by just googling `"ï»¿" python`.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error, but you might try `data = numpy.loadtxt(experiment["csv"], delimiter=",", encoding=None)`